# Is it possible to attach documents in the sharepoint designer email?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer-workflow

we currently have a requirement to attach a document in the email that would be sending from sharepoint designer.The site is currently in the on-premise environment.

is there any way to achieve this requirement?

any samples or implementation suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a link in the email workflow. When you receive the email, click the URL in the email message could open the file.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the help! but our requirements needs to have an attachments in the email instead of link

Comment: Per my knowledge, this seems impossible.